# Find_element in python selenium to click a button

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the login button a website, nothing has worked so far
I tried using
`signInButton =browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sg-btn.sg-blue.sg-element')` The webpage close immediately after this without anything happening

```
signInButton =browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sg-btn')
```

`signInButton =browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="sg-btn.sg-blue.sg-element"]')` 
it passes this error : Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="sg-btn.sg-blue.sg-element"]"}

and this is the HTML code from the website

```
<div class="vrm-panel--form__button-container">
                            <button class="sg-btn sg-blue sg-element" ng-class="{'sg-orange':isBeta()}" type="submit" data-i18n="login.login" fdprocessedid="6u6oz">Login</button>
                        </div>
```

The second one I tried using sg-btn lands me at a different page entirely

Public URL: [https://vrm.victronenergy.com/login][1]

Comment: Please post the error stack as well.

Comment: I have done so @KunduK

Comment: Please share the url if it is public. It seems element either inside iframe or shadow-root element.

Comment: It's public, thanks @KunduK

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath was wrong bu css selector looks fine. However it seems synchronisation isssue.
Use WebDriverWait() and wait for element_to_be_clickable() and following xpath.
you need import below libraries as well.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']")))
element.click();
```

Comment: Thanks, though it's giving me the same problem as the css selector, where the webpage would close without letting me login.